# Is it wrong to link one database to another in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, docker, microservices

Since we know the architecture of microservice and Docker. Do you think it is wrong to use the same "posgres" in two microservices but with two separate databases?
I will explain with an example: ‌
One service is responsible for managing the database of users and another is responsible for managing the database of posts (on the blog).
I want to use a "posgres" but how can I connect this database optimally? (There is a function in "posgres" called `dblink`. Is it correct and optimal to use it?)
I use queues to connect these two services and I do not want to create separate posgres for each micro.

```
docker containers:
  - user (manage user info with rest api)
  - post (manage user's post with rest api)

posgresql:
  - database name: user
    - table name: user
       - columns: firstname, lastname, username, id
  - database name: post
    - table name: post
       - columns: userId, title, content
```

Note: ‌ A database can be anything like postgres or mysql ....
I hope I was able to explain what I want correctly :)

Comment: There is `Postgres` and `Postgresql`, there is no `posgres` or `posgresql`.

Comment: Why don't you use one database with two tables? Remember that a Relational database is one with relations between two or more tables. Having a policy of one table per database rather goes against the whole point of using a relational database.

Comment: Unrelated but `dblink` in Postgresql has long been superseded by the far superior foreign data wrappers and [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html).

Comment: The main goal on microservices is to be able to make changes in a service without having any dependencies on other services. As long as each service don't access the other database (and by doing that creates a dependency between the services), I don't see a problem in have both databases in the same Postgres instance.

Comment: What MySQL calls a "database" is in reality a schema. So if you did use two "databases" in MySQL, you would use two _schemas_ inside one database in Postgres. Then you can indeed have a foreign key between the two tables.

Comment: Please describe what you mean with the terms "the same postgres" and "database".

Answer (score 0):

The advice to not share databases between microservices largely arises out of the fact that requiring two services to have the same data model inhibits the services' ability to evolve independently.

So having separate databases within the same physical DBMS* instance doesn't violate that, and because you typically can't express (or aren't expressing) relations between tables in different databases, if there's a reason in the future to move the databases to separate instances you can do that in a fairly straightforward way.

There's still a SPOF, and you'll need to decide if you're OK with that.

Jonathan Willcock brings up a very good point that in this example, both databases only have a single table, which kind of defeats a major benefit of using a relational DB like Postgres.  You might find it worth having the `post` DB include a rudimentary `user` table so that the `post` service can validate that a post is attributed to an actually existing user.

*: to some extent, the tendency which crept in over the past 20 or so years to use database to both mean the collection of tables and the process/server providing access to the database and interpreting queries, etc. (what in an earlier time was called the DataBase Management System) breeds confusion like this.